# Python/Pytest fixture value depending on test number

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I have created a @pytest.fixture(scope="class") inside which I have added  steps in the selenium:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def test_setup1(test_setup):
    driver.click_element()
    driver.enter_price()
    driver.enter_year('1997') <--- test-dependent element
    many steps
    ...
```

Is it possible that one of the elements e.g. driver.enter_year() depends on the element inside test?
For example:

```
def test_order_1 (self, test_setup1):

    date = 1998
    assert element_in_alert('Succes')


def test_order_2 (self, test_setup1):

    date = 1994
    assert element_in_alert('Succes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using [indirect fixture parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization):

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def test_setup1(request, test_setup):
    driver.click_element()
    driver.enter_price()
    driver.enter_year(request.param)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_setup1", ["1998"], indirect=True)
def test_order_1 (self, test_setup1):
    assert element_in_alert('Succes')

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_setup1", ["1994"], indirect=True)
def test_order_2(test_setup1):
    assert element_in_alert('Succes')
```

This parametrizes the fixture by writing the parameter(s) into `request.param`. This is usually used to pass more than one parameter value to the fixture, and if your tests are similar except for that value, you can also do this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_setup1", ["1994", "1998"], indirect=True)
def test_order(test_setup1):
    assert element_in_alert('Succes')
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and factual response. You helped me a lot. Greetings,